# Is it possible to create several Open Graph objects on the same web resource/URL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Or each object has to own a separate web page in order to use FB meta markup?

Answer (score 0):

Every object must have a page!

Citing the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/):

> Open Graph objects are simply web pages with `<meta>` tags containing Open Graph information in the `<head>` section of the page. These tags describe the object’s type, the object’s name and other key information.

Comment: Yeah, i know that - the question is how can i overcome the need to create page per object as some of the objects I want to share, don't have their own page

Comment: Why would you like do sharing of something you call objects that not fit definition of OG object and still need to create 'em without pages associated??? Why not just use Feed Dialog or Graph API for sharing this data?

Comment: Simple use case - let's say i have a page with two pictures and want to publish on Opengraph when you voted that picture or another (and i don't have separate page for each picture). Make sense?

Comment: Case makes sence but why you need to create OpenGraph object (that should have page by spec) for something that not important in your application to deserve a full page. You not required to create objects for everything you share...

Comment: You can represent an image as property for subject/topic which is voted